# Spring Web MVC annotations not working with Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am unable to make Spring Web MVC Annotation Configuration to work with Tomcat 7 and Eclipse. Any URL I hit returns "404".

I have following code.

Root Configuration

```
package com.jfasoftware.messanger.initializer;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.jfasoftware.messanger.config", "com.jfasoftware.messanger.controllers" })

public class BusinessLogicConfiguration
{}
```

Web Configuration

```
package com.jfasoftware.messanger.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.jfasoftware.messanger.controllers" })
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    //A JSP view resolver
    public  ViewResolver    viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver            viewResolver        = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        System.out.println("\nTrying to resolve\n");
        viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        viewResolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);

        return  viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    //Static Content handling
    public  void            configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer   configurer)
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Application Configuration

```
package com.jfasoftware.messanger.config;


import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.jfasoftware.messanger.initializer.BusinessLogicConfiguration;


public class ApplicationConfiguration   extends     AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return   new Class<?>[] { BusinessLogicConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return  new Class<?>[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        System.out.println("\nStarted\n");
        return  new String[] { "/*" };
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.jfasoftware.messanger.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import  static  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;

@Controller

public class HomePageController
{
    @RequestMapping (value="/")
    public  String      getHome()
    {
        System.out.println("\nJSR\n");
        return  "home";
    }
}
```

Please guide what is going wrong.

Comment: Are there any stack traces in the logs on startup?

Comment: No traces at all, no errors.

Comment: Do you have the home.jsp available in the `WEB-INF/views/` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have. Tomcat serves a static file but returns 404 for any other URL.

Comment: Can you show us your web.xml?

Comment: OS is Windows7. I am not using any "web.xml" since I want to use complete code based configuration.

Comment: Do you have a `home.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/views/`? You are also aware that you are duplicating everything? All is loaded in the `ContextLoaderListener` and the `DispatcherServlet` loads all web related stuff again.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have the home.jsp in /WEB-INF/views. I am not sure how I am duplicating anything.

Comment: Your `WebConfiguration` is being loaded by both the `ContextLoaderListener` (root context) and `DispatcherServlet`. Effectively duplicating all bean instances defined in there.